# PostgreSQL unable to access

Tags: c++, postgresql

I can't access database from C++
every time it just throws error: `FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "testuser"`

**I had tried:**

Reinstalling postgresql11 to postgresql12
Creating user
Creating database with owner testuser
Changing pg_hba.conf localhost from peer to md5
Changing the password of user multiple times
Rebooting computer
Restarting Service

here is the code:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

int main() {
    try {
        connection C("dbname = relay user = testuser password = 1234 hostaddr = 127.0.0.1 port =             5432");
        if (C.is_open()) 
            cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
        else {
            cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        C.close();
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
             cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
             return 1;
    }
}

TEST(postgreDB_test_trivial, trivial_test) {
     main();
}
```

I allowed even firewall access for ports

I don't have any more ideas on how to resolve this.

Comment: Please, add part of your `pg_hba.conf` with `testuser` access rules.

Comment: You would not be getting this error if you really were really using md5.  Whatever you tried to do to pg_hba.conf was not successful.  Make sure you edit the correct line of the correct file, and restart the server afterwards.  And show us all of the uncommented lines of pg_hba.conf

Comment: In addition to above I would use  ```host``` instead of ```hostaddr```. Also not sure if it a cut/paste error or not, but it would not hurt to get rid of that long empty part in ```port=  ```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that uninstalling Postgres11 and installing Postgres12 left pg_hba.conf with different setting after I restarted service so I needed to change everything to `trust` in pg_hba.conf to get it to work